# Deploying Spinnaker to PCF

Tags: spinnaker

I am very new to this and I want to know how to deploy spinnaker to PCF (on closed network) using spring cloud spinnaker. Do we need to build components of spinnaker before deploying, or can we directly push spring-cloud-spinnaker jar file to space. Please guide me with some reference.

Answer (score 0):

You no longer have to build all submodules anymore. Just build the project and push to your PCF environment. From there you can use it per ref docs.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the answer, I just want to know the difference between jar that is generated by building the project and the one available in spring cloud spinnaker blog (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-spinnaker)

Comment: The JAR built in the source is released to artifactory, from which you can download through that website. This JAR is a Spring Boot application used to deploy all the parts of Spinnaker into CF.

Comment: I am a bit confused Greg. What did you mean by 'build the project' ? which project are you referring here.

Comment: You can either pull down Spring Cloud Spinnaker from http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-spinnaker or you can build it from source from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-spinnaker. This is the tool we have to deploy Spinnaker into CF installations.

Spring Cloud Spinnaker, built as a JAR, can be pushed to any CF instance (with 8GB RAM + 4GB disk) can then install Spinnaker.

Comment: Greg, I pushed the JAR to a CF instance and after filling the details, i got the following error: "2017-03-14T15:39:14.374+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] 2017-03-14 10:09:14.373 ERROR 14 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to resolve MavenResource: org.springframework.cloud:orca-app:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT] with root cause".

Comment: @sivaprasad, we are in the process of finding a community representative to pick up and run with Spring Cloud Spinnaker. Hence, I don't have any updates for you right now.